# Template binding to ScaleTransform not work in Custom Control

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, scaletransform, layouttransform

I created simple custom control which derive from Control.

This control has 2 DP which I bind in xaml on ScaleTransform.

**Code behind.**

```
public class MyControl : Control
{
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ScaleXProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ScaleX", typeof (double), typeof (MyControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnScaleXChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScaleYProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ScaleY", typeof (double), typeof (MyControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnScaleYChanged));

                public double ScaleX
    {
        get { return (double) GetValue(ScaleXProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ScaleXProperty, value); }
    }

    public double ScaleY
    {
        get { return (double) GetValue(ScaleYProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ScaleYProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

**XAML.**

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

                    <Border.LayoutTransform>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{TemplateBinding ScaleX}" ScaleY="{TemplateBinding ScaleY}" />
                    </Border.LayoutTransform>


                    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                           VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                           Source="{TemplateBinding Icon}"
                           StretchDirection="Both" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I use MyControl in Window. After I changed ScaleX and ScaleY properties in Window code behind  LayoutTransform is no fire.

So I added handlers to MyControl for ScaleX and ScaleY. I these handlers I manualy do ScaleTransform. This works. So where is problem in TemplateBinding?

With this workaround ScaleTransform works.

```
    private static void OnScaleXChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is MyControl)
        {
            var ctrl = d as MyControl;

            var x = (double) e.NewValue;

            ctrl.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform(x, ctrl.ScaleY);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You have probably hit one of the many limitations of `TemplateBinding`.

So instead use the equivalent `Binding` with **relative source** as the **templated parent** which is semantically equivalent to `TemplateBinding` but (slightly) heavier:

```
<ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ScaleX,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ScaleY="{Binding ScaleY,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
```